# What is the best way to import this very large xml file into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, xml, import

I have a XML file with 95 gb of data (1444 mio rows). I need to import some of the data into a SQL Server table.

I have made a sample file that I'm trying to import into my SQL Server with the following code. I don't get any errors, but I also don't get any data in the table.

Sample file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnJeuk8W8KbEjblueb6bjKaDWJ5XAw?e=2molDZ

```
CREATE DATABASE DMR_DB2
GO

USE DMR_DB2
GO

CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    XMLData XML,
    LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\kn\Desktop\ESStatistikListeModtag-20220911-222128\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

--SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML


DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT KoeretoejIdent, KoeretoejArtNummer, KoeretoejArtNavn
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ESStatistikListeModtag_I/StatistikSamling/Statistik')
WITH 
(
KoeretoejIdent [varchar](50) '@KoeretoejIdent',
KoeretoejArtNummer [varchar](100) '@KoeretoejArtNummer',
KoeretoejArtNavn [varchar](100) 'KoeretoejArtNavn'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Comment: "What is best" is a *very* subjective term; can you be more specific on what *you* would define as "best"?

Comment: Also, please don't post a link to a file sharing site for us to download the file. Many of the users that write answers here are experience professions and know all too well the dangers and foolishness of downloading a file from a complete stranger on the internet. As a user with 1 reputation and who has signed up *today*, with the greatest respect, we have no reason why we should trust that content. If you want/need to include something in your question, then it should be within the question, not an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It works for your small XML sample.

Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML()` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.

As @Lamu already pointed out, SQL Server XML type column can hold up to 2 GB XML.

**For 95 GB you would need to use SSQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).**

SSIS has no limitation on the XML fie size. It will handle whatever the Operation System (OS) file system allows.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tbl;

CREATE TABLE tbl (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlColumn XML
);

INSERT INTO tbl(XmlColumn)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\Downloads\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://skat.dk/dmr/2007/05/31/')
SELECT c.value('(KoeretoejIdent/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as KoeretoejIdent
    , c.value('(KoeretoejArtNummer/text())[1]', 'INT') as KoeretoejArtNummer
    , c.value('(KoeretoejArtNavn/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') as KoeretoejArtNavn
FROM tbl
   CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/ESStatistikListeModtag_I/StatistikSamling/Statistik') AS t(c);
```

Comment: Considering that the OP claims that the XML file is **95GB** then it isn't going to fit in an `xml` value; it can only hold up to *2GB*.